# How to get boundfield value, or am I totally wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am follwing [this tutorial,](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html) he is using templatefield and then putting textbox in it for displaying data, like this,

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblitemUsr" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserName") %>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtftrusrname" runat="server"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvusername" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtftrusrname" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validaiton"/>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

then while updating gridview he is doing this,

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Employee_Details set City='" + txtcity.Text + "',Designation='" + txtDesignation.Text + "' where UserId=" + userid, con);
```

whereas what I am doing is,

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="userName" HeaderText="User" ItemStyle-Width="120px" />
```

Now how can I get boundfield value while updating SQL statement as there is no txtbox ?

My GridView declaration,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        CellPadding="5" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" Width="800px" AllowPaging="True"
        PageSize="5" GridLines="Horizontal" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
        OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" 
        OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" >
```

Comment: I don't want to use textboxes

Comment: yeah got you..!! you want bound field values in your `gvDetails_RowUpdating()` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set the most important thing `DataKeyNames` in your `<asp:Gridview></asp:GridView>` declaration, first add that and then,

You may try like this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

                int userid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["userid"]);
                string City= ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text.Trim();
                string Designation = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text.Trim();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Employee_Details set City='" + City + "',Designation='" + Designation + "' where UserId=" + userid, con);
                // 
                // other Code snippets
                //
                GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
                BindGridview();

    }
```

You will have to provide `cell[n]` values of cell that you want in code behind.

Comment: I know that you're just using the code that the OP used, but please be aware of [the dangers of concatenating user input into SQL strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) like that.  One should use parameterized queries in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use BoundFields instead of TemplateFields, you can find the values input by your users via your `GridView1_RowUpdating` event handler.  It has an argument of type [`GridViewUpdateEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.aspx).  All you have to do is cycle through the "NewValues" collection to get the values for the columns you need to update.

Also, you should never ever concatenate user input directly into SQL strings.  This is a well known vulnerability to malicious attacks called "SQL Injection".  User parameters instead (I have included them in my example below).

Here's an example:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string city = "";
    string designation = "";

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in e.NewValues)
    {
        if(entry.Key == "City")
        {
            city = entry.Value.ToString();
        }
        if(entry.Key == "Designation")
        {
            designation = entry.Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Employee_Details set City=@City, Designation=@Designation where UserId=@UserId", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Designation", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    cmd.Paramters["@City"].Value = city;
    cmd.Paramters["@Designation"].Value = designation;
    cmd.Paramters["@UserId"].Value = userid;
}
```

---

If you're going to use an SqlDataSource with the GridView, then none of that code is necessary.  The data source control will handle all of your update logic.  You just need to include an update command with parameters:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="myDataSource" runat="server"
    SelectCommand="Your select statement goes here"
    UpdateCommand="update Employee_Details set City=@City, Designation=@Designation where UserId=@UserId" />
```

Note that you need to name the parameters the same way that the "DataField" property of your BoundFields are.  So above you have `<asp:BoundField DataField="userName"...`, then you want to use "@userName" for that field in your UpdateCommand.

Comment: +1, I am bit confused sir, I want to use SQLDataSource instead of SQLCommand, can you give me an example please

Comment: @user13814 You didn't mention that anywhere in your question, but I will add some info about using the SqlDataSource as well =)

Comment: I will ask a new question now, hold on please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302494/how-to-add-update-parameter-to-sqldatasource-in-c-sharp

Comment: sorry but I am getting this exception for your code in foreach,  **The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.Add(string, string)' has some invalid arguments **

Comment: @user13814 Sorry, I did not test the code. I've updated those lines that caused the error - you need to specify a type (note that I used NVarChar for all of them, your data types might be different).