# How to add update parameter to SQLDataSource in c#

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms, sqldataadapter

In reference to my question,

[How to get boundfield value, or am I totally wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299942/how-to-get-boundfield-value-or-am-i-totally-wrong)

I am trying to add update parameter to a SQLDataSource using c# instead of ASP.NET but I am getting error,

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int userID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["userID"].ToString());
    string userName = "";
    string city = "";
    string updateStatement = "Update myTable set userName=@userName, city=@city where userID=@userID";

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in e.NewValues)
    {
        if (entry.Key == "userName")
            userName = entry.Value.ToString();
        if (entry.Key == "city")
            city = entry.Value.ToString();
    }

    using (SqlDataSource ds = new SqlDataSource(ConnectionString(), updateStatement))
    {
       ds.UpdateParameters.Add("@userName");  
        ds.UpdateParameters.Add("@city");
       ds.UpdateParameters.Add("@UserId");
    }

    gvDetails.EditIndex = -1;
    BindData();
}
```

How can I pass values of parameters :S

```
ds.UpdateParameters.Add("@userName");  
        ds.UpdateParameters.Add("@city");
       ds.UpdateParameters.Add("@UserId");
```

But I don't know the right syntax, can someone direct me in right direction please

Comment: Wrong syntax, I can't add paramters to SQLDataSource like that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use an SqlCommand instead of SqlDataSource:

```
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString())
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateStatement, connection)) {
    connection.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", userName));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@city", city));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", userID));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

Comment: +1, Can you also explain, why I should use SQLCommand not SqlDataSource please

Comment: SqlDataSource is intended for databinding to controls on a WebForm.  It's way overkill for what you're doing, particularly when you're trying to do it manually.  If you want to go the databinding route then it's the right choice.

Comment: 1+ no need of creating SqlDataSource here.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use SQLDataSource, then I believe the syntax is.

```
ds.UpdateParameters.Add("userName", "someDefaultValue");
```

No '@' and you can supply the default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add parameters to [`SqlDataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd0cb3we.aspx). You can add [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) instead. Try something similar like this;

```
string updateStatement = "Update myTable set userName=@userName, city=@city where userID=@userID";

using (SqlDataSource ds = new SqlDataSource(ConnectionString(), updateStatement))
{       
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateStatement);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName");  
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@city");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId");
        cmd.Paramters["@City"].Value = city;
        cmd.Paramters["@userName"].Value = userName;
        cmd.Paramters["@UserId"].Value = userID;

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but you said I can't add parameters to SQLDataSource ? is this something else then, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updateparameters(v=vs.80).aspx    , I might be wrong ?

Comment: With `UpdateParameters` property, you can specify which parameters will use in your update command of your SqlDataSource.

Comment: sorry but I am not really sure, how above code will going to work as it's not executing anything. but I give it a go anyway, thanks

Comment: SqlDataSource  accept select statement, there is a property to set update statement. but here on row updating no point of creating SqlDataSource  just for updating database. Hellfire's answer provide better solution.